# How to find current controller or action in routes.php in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, routes

I try lots of methods to find current controller and action in cakephp routing, but I didn't got answer. Is there any method to find controller and action in routing. If yes, please help me. Or if there is any other way to find these, Please tell me.

Comment: It would be a good idea to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It's the routes that decide to what controller and action a url maps to. When `routes.php` is being loaded the routing process has still not been done (since you are still setting up routes), so you cannot know controller or action is in `routes.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If the website formatted something like this :

> www.johndoe.test/test/test_action/

then probably it can be found on test controller but of course that depends on the settings of the website on how the developer configured it. It may also be found on routes.php like @ADmad said.